# Can I receive a response from a socket.emit request without setting up a handler for the reponse?

Tags: sockets, socket.io

So this is what I have going on right now:

`server.js`

```
socket.on('callSQL', function(){

        connection.query('...', function(err, rows) {

                  socket.emit('sqlResponse', { 'sqlResponse': rows });
                  console.log(rows);
        });
});
```

And in `client.js`

```
socket.emit('callSQL')
socket.on('sqlResponse', function(data){
   console.log(data);
});
```

My question is would it be possible to do something like:

```
var rows = socket.emit('callSQL');
```

And receive have the `sqlResponse` stuff returned to me? Or is that not how `sockets.io` does things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible given the inherent asynchronous nature of socket communication. As soon as your first 'emit' is called, flow has moved on.

This is mostly desirable as you'd want to avoid 'locking up' your application while it waited to receive a response.

The solution you already have, emitting and then then waiting for a response, is your best bet.